# Desktop Shortcut in Desktop Bridge App. Where do we get the AppUserModelId

Tags: .net, uwp, shortcut, desktop-bridge

I'm trying to create a Desktop Shortcut when my Desktop Bridge App is used for the first time.

I successfully can create a Desktop Shortcut pointing to the `Application.ExecutablePath`, but that generates an error when the user open the shortcuts. The error is regarding the user not having permission access to that folder.

I have research in the internet and found that the proper way is to do it with shell as this: `shell:AppsFolder\{AppUserModelId}`

But at least in Desktop-Bridge, when I instantiate `Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInfo`, it is always null.

The question being, where I can get the `AppUserModelId`, or is there another way to create a Desktop Shortcut in UWP/Desktop Bridge.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question where to get the `AppUserModelID`:

The AUMID for a packaged app (DesktopBridge or UWP app) is simply composed of `PackageFamilyName + "!" + PackageRelativeAppID`.

With the Fall Creators Update we have also added a property on `AppListEntry` so you don't need to compose it yourself:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.core.applistentry#Properties

So to get the AUMID for your app you can call this:

```
string aumid = (await Package.Current.GetAppListEntriesAsync()).First().AppUserModelId;
```

(this is assuming that your package contains a single app)

Comment: I can't get this to compile in VS 2015, it says AppUserModelId is not found in AppListEntry object. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

> I have research in the internet and found that the propper way is to do it with shell as this: `shell:AppsFolder{AppUserModelId}`

You could use the above way to create a shortcut for your app in Windows 8.1, but it is not recommend in Windows 10. Nowadays, you could drag your app's icon from `Start` to desktop to create a shortcut directly.

[image]

> But at least in Desktop-Bridge when I instanciate `Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInfo` it is always null.

The `Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInfo` unavailable to a packaged desktop app. For more you could refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api) official documentation.