# How to update UWP libraries in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

I'm trying to implement the code in the question:
[Desktop Shortcut in Desktop Bridge App. Where do we get the AppUserModelId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054613/desktop-shortcut-in-desktop-bridge-app-where-do-we-get-the-appusermodelid)

I want to get the Aumid for my app by given code in the IAPWrapper based DLL project in Visual Studio 2015:

```
string aumid = (await Package.Current.GetAppListEntriesAsync()).First().AppUserModelId;
```

But I get the build error that "'AppListEntry' does not contain a definition for 'AppUserModelId' and no extension method 'AppUserModelId'". How do I update my UWP libraries for Visual Studio 2015 in order to solve this problem?

Comment: The `AppUserModelId` property was added in version 16299 of the SDK and requires Windows 10 version 1709 or later. The SDK can be downloaded from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows/downloads/sdk-archive?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AppUserModelId` property was added in version 16299 of the SDK.

It requires Windows 10 version 1709 or later and is only officially supported on Visual Studio **2017** and later so you should upgrade.

Comment: I updated to VS 2022 and it recommended to upgrade my project to use .NET framework 4.8. I did that but the same error message is still there. Why it is not getting the new definition as pointed out in the original question?

Comment: What's the `TargetPlatformVersion` in your packaging project?

Comment: Thanks for following up. The problem was with references, I removed and added them again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible according to various articles that I found.

[How to install (v142) Build tools in Visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56901371/how-to-install-v142-build-tools-in-visual-studio)

Each visual studio edition has a limit on the last toolset that it can use. I will need to upgrade to a later Visual Studio.